# How doing input-output file on C?

Tags: c, cryptography, xor

I am found this code in some books:

```
enter code here
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    FILE *in, *out;
    char *key;
    int byte;

     if (argc !=4) {
     printf ("Usage: xorer <key> <input_file> <output_file>\n");
      return 1;
      }

       key = argv[1];

       if ((in = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) != NULL) {
       if ((out = fopen(argv[3], "wb")) != NULL) {

       while ((byte = getc(in)) != EOF)
       {
       if (!*key) key = argv[1]; 
         byte^= *(key++);
       putc(byte,out);
     }

   fclose(out); } 
   fclose(in); }

  return 0;
```

}

This code must doing next thing(simple cryptography with XOR operation):

```
input = ]VTYJQC]aGC_PDJ[{RJ[EEMLA  //encrypted key

key = creature_creautre_creature // string for crypting
--------------------------------
Output >$18>$18>$18>$18>$18>$18>$  // ASCII symbols for XOR crypting
```

But code doing nothing (compiling without errors)!I'm created input.data, input.in files in code directory.It's don't work.Say,please,how doing input_file and output_file ?

Comment: "My code does not work" is not a **specific** problem statement. Please provide more information. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled the code correctly, then running the code with no arguments will print the usage information, which is also found in the source code itself:

```
Usage: xorer <key> <input_file> <output_file>\n
```

So, if you want to encrypt (decrypt) file called input.txt, found in the current directory, using the key "ABC" and write the output (encrypted / decrypted data) to file output.txt, you would use the program as follows:

```
xorer ABC input.txt output.txt
```

You will find the encrypted (decrypted) file output.txt in the current directory.

This should answer your specific question about providing input and output to the program.  If you have other related questions, please let us know.